# Angular 8 Dialogflow catbot with api-ai-javascript@2.0.0-beta.21 Not loading up on IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, dialogflow-es

My angular 8 application was working fine on both Chrome and IE11.
But now it is not loading up on IE11 after I added chatbot code which communicates with [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/) with the help of [api-ai-javascript@2.0.0-beta.21](https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-ai-javascript#200-beta21) lib. It works fine on chrome.
Also, I do not see any error on the console of IE.

I followed almost all available links on a similar topic and experienced that even the samples available on Github are behaving in a similar way. If you open [this](http://smartbot-mlabouardy.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) on chrome it works but not in IE11. Similarly, [this](https://github.com/SiddAjmera/MovieChatbotUsingAngularMaterial) GitHub example works fine on Chrome but not on IE11.

It will be of great help if someone can guide me. So that the chatbot code starts working on IE11 as well.

I am open to posting any code if required for an answer. Here is my Chat service class.

```
import { ApiAiClient } from 'api-ai-javascript/es6/ApiAiClient';
....
export class ChatService {
....
readonly client = new ApiAiClient({ accessToken: this.token });
....

public converse(msg: string) {

  const userMessage = new Msg(msg, 'user');

  this.update(userMessage);
  return this.client.textRequest(msg) 
 .then(res => { 
       const speech = res.result.fulfillment.speech; 
       const botMessage = new Msg(speech, 'bot'); 
       this.update(botMessage); 
  });
}
....
```

Comment: Try to use F12 developer Network tools to check whether the related resource load success?Besides, from the dialogflow api and the dialogflow-javascript-client library ([this thread](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client/issues/48)), I'm not finding the related description about it support IE browser.So, I think it is better to confirm with Dialogflow whether it support IE browser, or is there need to add any polyfill for IE browser.

Comment: Besides, here are some article about Build a Chatbot With Dialogflow, you could check them: [article 1](https://www.labsexplorer.com/news/create-a-simple-angular-chatbot-with-google-dialogflow_494) and [article 2](https://fireship.io/lessons/build-a-chatbot-with-dialogflow/).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT : Thanks for your suggestions. I went through the articles. Will update here in case they help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deprecated
>
> This Dialogflow client library and Dialogflow API V1 have been
>   deprecated and will be shut down on October 23th, 2019. Please migrate
>   to Dialogflow API V2.

For API V2 you can follow https://chatbotslife.com/dialogflow-v2-rest-api-communication-6cf7ab66ab36

Comment: I have moved out the chat bot interaction code from Angular and now using back-end to return the response for user interaction.  This will keep me prepared for any such future updates too. Thanks for the pointer and blog it helped.